# Detect photos vs rendered images

Tags: image, image-processing, numpy, photos

I'm trying to, given a random image and using NumPy, detect whether it's a photo vs a "rendered" image (like a map). The images can be colour or black & white, and gradients in rendered images might easily use 0-255, so counting colours won't help for greyscale. I can't use EXIF/etc metadata.

Approaches I've quickly tried so far, without anything jumping out:

- Converting to greyscale, then looking at a histogram
- 2D FFT then looking at histograms of the frequencies per band (as RGB and YUV)
- Looking at the means & standard deviation of the luminance
- Edge detection using [Canny](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canny_edge_detector) and [Sobel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobel_operator) filters
- Comparing [GLCM](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/plot_glcm.html) properties for random 21x21 patches from each image
- Compress images as either JPEG (good for photos) or Deflate (aka. PNG) (good for maps) and compare bits-per-pixel

(feel free to suggest I go back and have another look)

I'm generally analysing random samples of larger areas rather than small crops like the examples shown below, so approaches that ignore occasional edge cases should work.

Current promising leads are described below, ideas I haven't looked at yet are:

- None left

Are there any algorithms/approaches that I should be looking at?

#### HSV

Still a Work in Progress for black and white images :) -- but the hue & saturation of all the rendered images is *much* spikier than the photographs, and generally has a 2-5x higher maxima  as well.

```
image_hsv = skimage.color.rgb2hsv(image_rgb)

hue_band, sat_band, val_band = np.squeeze(np.dsplit(image_hsv, 3))

band_hist, _ = np.histogram(hue_band.ravel(), bins=256)
peak_idx = np.signal.argrelmax(band_hist, order=20)[0]

peaks = band_hist[peak_idx]
```

#### Contrast

Examining the contrast seems to be slightly better, calculated via the code below. Photos generally seem to be <= 130, and maps generally are >= 150. Though black and white maps have a very low contrast (eg. 11 for the image below):

```
# image_rgb is a 3D numpy array: [
#                                 [ [r,g,b], [r,g,b], ... ],
#                                 [ [r,g,b], [r,g,b], ... ],
#                                 ...
#                                ]

# these constants from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_luminance
rgb2lum = numpy.array([0.2126, 0.7152, 0.0722])
luminance = numpy.dot(image_rgb, rgb2lum)

# for B&W images, luminance == image_bw already
rms_contrast = numpy.sqrt(numpy.mean(numpy.square(luminance)))
```

### Current approach

What I've currently gone with is:

1. Analysing up to 8x 512x512px random patches from images, which all vote for a result:

   1. For RGB images, convert the patch to HSV colour
   2. Creating a histogram (256 bins) of either the B&W data or the Hue band (`np.histogram()`)
   3. Count the non-empty bins in the histogram, if less than 100 the vote is 'map'.
   4. Get the peaks of the histogram (`signal.argrelmax(hist, order=20)`)
   5. If the maximum peak is >9% of the total pixels in the band *and* the maximum peak is >=2x as large as the mean of the peaks, then the vote is 'map'.
   6. Otherwise, the vote is 'photo'
2. If 50% of the votes from patches are 'map', the result is 'map'

Is pretty good when run across colour images, and the results get better again if you have multiple images in a dataset and can re-vote again on a per-image level.

B&W images are still a bit hit or miss.

### Example images

High-contrast colour photo. Some can be quite over-exposed:
[image: High-contrast colour photo]

Low-contrast colour photo:
[image: Low-contrast colour photo]

High-contrast B&W photo. Again, some can be quite over-exposed:
[image: High-contrast B&W photo]

Low-contrast B&W photo:
[image: Low-contrast B&W photo]

Low-contrast colour map:
[image: Low-contrast colour map]

High-contrast map:
[image: High-contrast map]

B&W Map:
[image: B&W Map]

Comment: I think this is beyond the scope of StackOverflow. That is, I think it violates "If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much." on [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: @farenorth "Photo or not?" is about as simple as I could make it :) I agree about classification of images or object detection or other more complex stuff, but hopefully there's a relatively straightforward answer out there which can help others too

Comment: I agree that this question might receive better answers on a site like stats.stackexchange.com. However, I'll make a quick suggestion here, which is to try frequency-space features for this task. Natural images tend to have fairly regular frequency spectra with a lot of power in the low frequencies, while it seems like "rendered" images are likely to have more power in the high frequencies.

Comment: idea to check for flat areas with same color, generated images even with gradients will have these, while real photos rarely. Flat areas in photos will have lots of colors usually.

Comment: Is "photo or not" question out of scope of SO? Not focused enough? I really cannot understand why this question is closed.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that this may be slightly out of scope for SO. Perhaps submit it to [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/)?

To get you started, I would suggest looking at [texture features](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_texture) of each image, rather than colors or contrast. The edge detection idea you had is a step in the right direction.

Once you convert each image to a set of numerical texture features, you could use a [binary classifier](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/supervised_learning.html#supervised-learning) to separate the photos from the synthetic images.